# Does the Korteweg-de Vries equation suffer from the Ostrogradsky instability?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, stability-theory, soliton-theory

The [Korteweg-de Vries equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation) is 
$$\partial_t\phi+\partial^3_x\phi-6\phi\partial_x\phi=0
$$

Apparently, it comes from the Lagrangian
$$L=\frac{1}{2}\partial_t\psi\partial_x\psi+(\partial_x\psi)^3-\frac{1}{2}(\partial^2_x\psi)^2
$$

where $\partial_x\psi=\phi$ (as derived in the Wikipedia article).

This Lagrangian is non-degenerate (as per the requirement of the [Ostrogradsky theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02210.pdfy)) since $\partial^2_{\psi_{xx}}L\neq 0$. Therefore, this system ought to suffer from the [Ostrogradsky instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability).

Normally, that is interpreted to mean that it has no minimum energy (which is considered unphysical), but that interpretation relies on the Lagrangian depending on the second **time** derivative of the generalized coordinate (i.e. $\partial^2_t\psi$). Since this Lagrangian depends on the second derivative with respect to **position**, it could mean that the Ostrogradsky theorem doesn't apply or that the system is unbounded in momentum rather than energy or something else entirely - I just don't know.

**Does this system suffer from the Ostrogrady instability, and if so, what does that mean for the behaviour of the system?**

Comment: It would appear that the Ostrogrady Theorem does not apply (by the way, your first link is broken), since the second-order time derivative is not present (nor any higher-order derivatives).